# Program doesn't find installed lib in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, libs

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for ARM(arm64). After trying to install .deb file of Winscribe(armhf), logs show that I miss some package and installed it:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up windscribe-cli:armhf (1.4-51) ...
/usr/bin/windscribe: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/windscribe: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package windscribe-cli:armhf (--configure):
 installed windscribe-cli:armhf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 windscribe-cli:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After I tried to install libz.so.1 manually and succeed. Logs from apt:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Even after is shows me the top error as Windscribe doesn't find lib.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be a better question for serverfault than here (it's not a programming question).  On debian the setup script is in /var/lib/dpkg/info/{package}.postinst.  You can see what it does.  `ldconfig -p | grep libz` should confirm you have the library.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that forum. The return of the command:libzstd.so.1 (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1
        libz.so.1 (libc6,AArch64) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1, guess libs are okay